# Identify US county from from latitude and longitude using Python

Tags: python, geopy, yelp

I am using the codes below to identify US county. The data is taken from Yelp which provides lat/lon coordinate.

| id | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40.017544 | -105.283348 |
| 2 | 45.588906 | -122.593331 |

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_json("/Users/yelp/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json", lines=True, encoding='utf-8')

# Identify county
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="http")
df['county'] = geolocator.reverse(df['latitude'],df['longitude'])
```

The error was "TypeError: reverse() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given".

Comment: Perhaps latitude and longitude need to be a tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nominatim.reverse` takes coordinate pairs; the issue is that you are passing it pandas dataframe columns. `df['latitude']` here refers to the entire column in your data, not just one value, and since `geopy` is independent of `pandas`, it doesn't support processing an entire column and instead just sees that the input isn't a valid number.

Instead, try looping through the rows:

```python
county = []

for row in range(len(df)):
    county.append(geolocator.reverse((df['latitude'][row], df['longitude'][row])))
```

(Note the double brackets.)

Then, insert the column into the dataframe:

```python
df.insert(index, 'county', county, True)
```

(`index` should be what column position you want, and the boolean value at the end indicates that duplicate values are allowed.)

Comment: Thank you, I got the error "ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point" when trying this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @TrinhTrongAnh Does `geolocator.reverse((df['latitude'], df['longitude']))` (note the double parantheses) work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I go the same error: ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point.

Comment: @TrinhTrongAnh Weird. What about `geolocator.reverse(Point(latitude = df['latitude'], longitude = df['longitude']))`? (you may need to import `Point` from `geopy.point`). Apologies for the confusion; I've never used this module and I was following the documentation, but that appears to not work.

Comment: The documentation also says you can pass a list or tuple of lat/long tuples.  So you need triple parentheses.

Comment: I got new error when trying the Point approach: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Hi Mark, may you please explain further how the triple parentheses fit in the code? Thank you.

Comment: `geolocator.reverse([(df['latitude'], df['longitude'])])` should work based on what @MarkRansom describes

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue remains when I use triple parentheses : "ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point"

Comment: @TrinhTrongAnh Can you send me the JSON file as-is? It just occurred to me that I've never used panda and the issue might not be caused by misunderstanding the geopy documentation, it is probably something else.

Comment: The data is provided by Yelp available at https://www.yelp.com/dataset or it can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2dns31ezwgmcbt/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json?dl=0. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @TrinhTrongAnh Aha, I see my problem now. I found one issue but totally missed the other one. I've updated my answer; hope this helps!

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Thanks for your time. I've created a new column called 'county' using `df.insert(2, "county", '')` However, I got "KeyError: 2". Do you have any idea?

Comment: @TrinhTrongAnh Apparently you are supposed to insert the whole column at once, so I've added an updated version to my answer that should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the us census data, and geopandas.

imports

```
import urllib
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
​
```

get geometry data as a geopandas dataframe

```
src = [
    {
        "name": "counties",
        "suffix": ".shp",
        "url": "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_county_5m.zip",
    },
]
data = {}
print('gathering county data from census')
for s in src:
    f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(s["url"]).path.split("/")[-1])
    if not f.exists():
        r = requests.get(s["url"],stream=True,)
        with open(f, "wb") as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128): fd.write(chunk)
​
    fz = ZipFile(f)
    fz.extractall(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem))
​
    data[s["name"]] = gpd.read_file(
        f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).joinpath([f.filename
                                            for f in fz.infolist()
                                            if Path(f.filename).suffix == s["suffix"]][0])
    ).assign(source_name=s["name"])
gdf = pd.concat(data.values()).to_crs("EPSG:4326")
​
```

Lockport Illinois coordinates

```
query_point = Point(-88.057510, 41.589401)
```

use geopandas contains() to filter the data

```
contains = gdf.contains(query_point)
data = gdf[contains]
print(data['NAME'])
```

prints 'Will'

link to documentation:
https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.contains.html